# Can you add an ESC Key shortcut?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `Menustrip` Item on my `Form`, and it closes my `Form` when I press it. I want to make the shortcut key for my `MenuStrip` Item <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but in the "ShorcutKey" settings, it doesn't have an option for <kbd>Esc</kbd>, is there any way I can make it do that it is <kbd>Esc</kbd>? I have to make it show on the `MenuStrip` Item that <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the shortcut key.

Doing this does NOT work:

```
menuStripItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Escape;
```

Comment: What’s the situation? You may be better off with a `CancelButton`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct solution to this, You can use this workaround, Set the `ShortcutKeyDisplayString` in code

```
menuStripItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "ESC";
```

Within the `KeyDown` event of the form check if `ESC` is pressed and `Close()` the form.

Comment: I have a code that makes it so that I can press the ESC key to close the program. What I want to do is make it so that it shows in the shortcut key area, that the shortcut key is ESC

Comment: Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Then as i shown in my code you can set the `ShortcutKeyDisplayString` property as `Escape`. If you simply need to show ESC as shortcut key.

Answer (score 9):

Winforms is picky about the shortcut keystroke you select.  The rule is that it must be a function key (F1-F12) or another key with either `Keys.Control` or `Keys.Alt` included.  The bigger intention here is that you can't accidentally replace a normal key that might be used in, say, a `TextBox`.  The Escape key normally operates the cancel button of a dialog.

`Keys.Escape` is rather special; Alt+Escape and Ctrl+Escape cannot work, as they are global shortcut keys in Windows.

So you can't use the `ShortcutKeys` property; you have to recognize the Escape key differently.  Easily done in your Form class by overriding the `ProcessCmdKey()` method.  Paste this code into your form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: This will work for closing it, but i already have code for that. What I needed was to make it show the shortcut key.

Comment: @Dozer789 Even when you have code to close it, this code is better because you can prevent the default command-key process, `ESC` is a special command-key which may work unexpectedly in some case. So just disabling/overriding the default action would be better.

Comment: I might be using this code for my program, I don't remember. If I am not, I am probably going to use this code.

Comment: +1 This may not have been what the OP was looking for, but was exactly what I was looking for, and saved me adding my own question. Thanks so much.